# What do I need to build a C++ plugin on windows 7?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, windows, c++

I want to make a plugin in C++ and I *need* to write and build it in windows (Im better with *nix systems).

While I have skimmed the various updated C++Plugin docs I can understand if I need to build QGIS from source in windows in order to build extra plugins.

What do I need to have in order to build a plugin on windows 7? Is there any tutorial for windows users (especially windows compile-dummies!)